# Is it possible to have a window per sub-task/partition

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am working with Flink using data from a Kafka topic that has multiple partitions. Is it possible to have a window on each parallel sub-task/partition without having to use `keyBy` (as I want to avoid the shuffle). Based on the documentation, I can only choose between keyed windows (which requires a shuffle) or global windows (which reduces parallelism to 1).

The motivation is that I want to use a `CountWindow` to batch the messages with a custom trigger that also fires after a set amount of processing time. So per Kafka partition, I want to batch N records together or wait X amount of processing time before sending the batch downstream.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no good way to do that.

One workaround would be to implement the batching and timeout logic in a custom sink. You'd want to implement the `CheckpointedFunction` interface to make your solution fault tolerant, and you could use the `Sink.ProcessingTimeService.ProcessingTimeCallback` interface for the timeouts.

UPDATE:

Just thought of another solution, similar to the one in your comment below. You could implement a custom source that sends a periodic heartbeat, and broadcast that to a BroadcastProcessFunction.

Comment: Thanks for this. I suppose the limitation of that is that I would not be able to chain further operations on the Sink. For now, I have settled on a FlatMap and configured upstream to send periodic messages to "push" each batch through.